# How to increase tappable area of top navbar buttons in iOS PhoneGap/Corova Apps

Tags: ios, cordova, kendo-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I have been developing hybrid apps on iOS and the most glaring problem I am having is the back button that emulates the native back button on the top navbar has a much smaller area.

This may be due to the button being on the edge of the top edge of the screen and the webview doesn't interpret taps on the edge to be intended for the webview, maybe the status bar.

I have even enlarged the padding on the button element to the point where it takes up the whole top left corner of the screen and wont register a tap unless you aiming for 3.5mm beneath the top of the webview. On a native app you can aim 0mm away from the edge and it registers.

This may not seem that bad, however when you allow a long term iOS user that 3.5mm is very apparent, and their mental model of where a touch should register makes them immediately think the app is broken, instead of them tapping the wrong area.

I am interested in any other information regarding ways to minimize this discrepancy between native and hybrid, or proposed solutions/information leading to a better understanding on *why* this occurs.

Using Cordova / PhoneGap and Kendo Mobile to implement the app